# Cookies expiring too fast on android

Tags: php, android, cookies

I'm running a php website that keeps track of scores when a live card game is played. I'm using cookies to store variables like player names that last for 1 hour and are re-set every time a new score has been added. I don't store them in a session cookie, since I want to keep them stored on the system after a accidental shutdown.

All this works perfect on PC or Mac, runs great on iOS, but when it comes to android this seems to be a problem. When the website is visited from an android device, cookies seem to expire after less than 5 minutes, even though they are set to an hour.

Is there anybody else recognizing/resolving this?

Comment: are you using the default Android browser? which OS version? did you double confirm on other Android devices?

Comment: I tried it on a friends samsung tab. I dont know which OS, but I installed Chrome to verify it was not a browser problem. The same occured with the chrome browser. I did not have the opportunity to test it on an other android device.

Comment: Can you provide the public website link for us to test ?

Comment: the website is www.white-board.be, you have to choose "nieuwe kaarting" but the location is pass-protected. Is there any way I could send you the login information in private? Thanks in advance man.

Comment: Can you create a test account for us?

Comment: Yes. login and pass: "cookietest". Would you like to choose "ja" in the beta-test field? That way i can easily remove the test cases. The "schrijver" field should contain a name that you already used in the name fields above. I must say I changed the php-version of my host form 5.2 to 5.4. I asked someone else to test it on android and he didnt have any problems. I should check it out with the samsung tab that had trouble with it to be sure if the php upgrade fixed the issue.